# Отрисовать дерево,имея объект с глубокой вложенностью

Tags: javascript, рекурсия, дерево

привет
есть у нас такой объект:

```
{
  name: "Frontend",
  skills: [
    {
      name: "HTML & CSS",
      skills: [
        {
          name: "Understanding block, inline and table models"
        },
        {
          name: "Stylesheets",
          skills: [
            {
              name: "Positioning",
              skills: [
                {
                  name: "static, relative and absolute, fixed, sticky"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              name: "Understanding of box model"
            },
            {
              name: "Understanding floating"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

должно получиться что то подобное
[image: должно получиться что то подобное]

я думаю в такой ситуации лу4ше использовать рекурсию, но не могу понять как создать html с вложенностью

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function OutputNameAndSkills(item, parentDOMElement) {
  // output item.name - li, add to parentDOMElement
  if (item.skills) {
    // create parent element for item.skills - ul inside the above li
    for (var i = 0; i < item.skills.length; i++) {
      OutputNameAndSkills(item.skills[i], <parent element for item.skills>);
    }
  }
}
```